# No operator ">>" matches these operands

Tags: c++, operands

I've look thoroughly throughout the website and couldn't find a solution to my unique problem.

The compiler keeps bring up the " No operator ">>" matches these  operands." message when I try to use this piece of code:

```
void readCustomerInfo()
{
ifstream in_stream;
int i = 0;

in_stream.open("Customers.dat");

string iDTemp;
string fntemp;
string lntemp;
float baltemp;
CustomerStatus stattemp;
int i = 0;
while (in_stream
    >> iDTemp
    >> fntemp
    >> lntemp
    >> baltemp
    >> stattemp)

{
    CCustomer temp(iDTemp, fntemp, lntemp, baltemp, stattemp);
    customers[i] = temp;
    i++;
}
```

the red error line appears ONLY under the >> that is immediately before stattemp.

CustomerStatus is an enum that looks like this:

```
enum CustomerStatus
{
INACTIVE,
ACTIVE,
};
```

CCustomer is a class.

I've tried my best to solve this and asked quite a few people, but I can't seem to wrap my head around solving the error.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: How are you expecting `>>` to read a `CustomerStatus`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to assign a value to an enum based on input from a file in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619732/how-to-assign-a-value-to-an-enum-based-on-input-from-a-file-in-c)

Comment: @user2357112 It's what I have tried so far and am unfamiliar with solving this kind of problem.

Comment: You will need to read the `enum` name as a string, then convert it to an `enum` type.

Comment: I suppose I should ask is there a way to create an overloaded insertion operator to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

The compiler doesn't know how to convert input from a file into an enum type, so you'll need some way of doing that. The error is due to it not knowing how to apply >> to the data it's getting.